# Taking first and last value in a rolling window

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

## Initial problem statement

Using pandas, I would like to apply function available for resample() but not for rolling().

This works:

```
df1 = df.resample(to_freq,
                  closed='left',
                  kind='period',
                   ).agg(OrderedDict([('Open', 'first'),
                                      ('Close', 'last'),
                                                        ]))
```

This doesn't:

```
df2 = df.rolling(my_indexer).agg(
                 OrderedDict([('Open', 'first'),
                              ('Close', 'last') ]))
>>> AttributeError: 'first' is not a valid function for 'Rolling' object

df3 = df.rolling(my_indexer).agg(
                 OrderedDict([
                              ('Close', 'last') ]))
>>> AttributeError: 'last' is not a valid function for 'Rolling' object
```

What would be your advice to keep first and last value of a rolling windows to be put into two different columns?

## EDIT 1 - with usable input data

```
import pandas as pd
from random import seed
from random import randint
from collections import OrderedDict

# DataFrame
ts_1h = pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01 00:00+00:00', end='2020-01-02 00:00+00:00', freq='1h')
seed(1)
values = [randint(0,10) for ts in ts_1h]
df = pd.DataFrame({'Values' : values}, index=ts_1h)

# First & last work with resample
resampled_first = df.resample('3H',
                              closed='left',
                              kind='period',
                             ).agg(OrderedDict([('Values', 'first')]))
resampled_last = df.resample('3H',
                             closed='left',
                             kind='period',
                            ).agg(OrderedDict([('Values', 'last')]))

# They don't with rolling
rolling_first = df.rolling(3).agg(OrderedDict([('Values', 'first')]))
rolling_first = df.rolling(3).agg(OrderedDict([('Values', 'last')]))
```

Thanks for your help!
Bests,

Comment: I don't understand what you try to do. Better show some example data and expected result.

Comment: This definitely needs an small example dataset, and an expected output, so we know we are talking about the same expectations.

Comment: @furas Hello furas and Erfan, thanks for your comment, I have added input data. In this basic example, I am using a fixed-size rolling window. In my normal data, I am using a varying-size windows (defined with CustomIndexer), so getting the first and last value of the rolling window would be for me best to do with first and last attributes of rolling, would they be existing, like for resample.
Thanks for any advice you can provide.

Comment: I don't understand what you try to do with `rolling` - what result do you expect. I think you try to do thing which can be done with other function - and rolling wasn't created for this (and will never work for this). Better create small data (without random) and expected result so we could run it again and again.

Comment: BTW: if you get all first values from rolling then you get the same `df` without last 2 elements - similar to `df[:-2]`.  if you get all last values from rolling then you get the same `df` without first 2 elements - similar to `df[2:]`.

Comment: how about `.agg(lambda row: rows[0])` (for first in window) and `.agg(lambda rows: rows[-1])` (for last in window)?

Comment: Thanks @furas, this does the trick! I have using more complex code to deal with this, but your proposal is neat, much cleaner!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use own function to get first or last element in rolling window

```
rolling_first = df.rolling(3).agg(lambda rows: rows[0])
rolling_last  = df.rolling(3).agg(lambda rows: rows[-1])
```

---

Example

```
import pandas as pd
from random import seed, randint

# DataFrame
ts_1h = pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01 00:00+00:00', end='2020-01-02 00:00+00:00', freq='1h')

seed(1)
values = [randint(0, 10) for ts in ts_1h]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Values' : values}, index=ts_1h)

df['first'] = df['Values'].rolling(3).agg(lambda rows: rows[0])
df['last']  = df['Values'].rolling(3).agg(lambda rows: rows[-1])

print(df)
```

Result

```
                          Values  first  last
2020-01-01 00:00:00+00:00       2    NaN   NaN
2020-01-01 01:00:00+00:00       9    NaN   NaN
2020-01-01 02:00:00+00:00       1    2.0   1.0
2020-01-01 03:00:00+00:00       4    9.0   4.0
2020-01-01 04:00:00+00:00       1    1.0   1.0
2020-01-01 05:00:00+00:00       7    4.0   7.0
2020-01-01 06:00:00+00:00       7    1.0   7.0
2020-01-01 07:00:00+00:00       7    7.0   7.0
2020-01-01 08:00:00+00:00      10    7.0  10.0
2020-01-01 09:00:00+00:00       6    7.0   6.0
2020-01-01 10:00:00+00:00       3   10.0   3.0
2020-01-01 11:00:00+00:00       1    6.0   1.0
2020-01-01 12:00:00+00:00       7    3.0   7.0
2020-01-01 13:00:00+00:00       0    1.0   0.0
2020-01-01 14:00:00+00:00       6    7.0   6.0
2020-01-01 15:00:00+00:00       6    0.0   6.0
2020-01-01 16:00:00+00:00       9    6.0   9.0
2020-01-01 17:00:00+00:00       0    6.0   0.0
2020-01-01 18:00:00+00:00       7    9.0   7.0
2020-01-01 19:00:00+00:00       4    0.0   4.0
2020-01-01 20:00:00+00:00       3    7.0   3.0
2020-01-01 21:00:00+00:00       9    4.0   9.0
2020-01-01 22:00:00+00:00       1    3.0   1.0
2020-01-01 23:00:00+00:00       5    9.0   5.0
2020-01-02 00:00:00+00:00       0    1.0   0.0
```

---

**EDIT:**

Using dictionary you have to put directly `lambda`, not string

```
result = df['Values'].rolling(3).agg({'first': lambda rows: rows[0], 'last':  lambda rows: rows[-1]})
print(result)
```

The same with own function - you have to put its name, not string with name

```
def first(rows):
    return rows[0]

def last(rows):
    return rows[-1]

result = df['Values'].rolling(3).agg({'first': first, 'last': last})
print(result)
```

---

Example

```
import pandas as pd
from random import seed, randint

# DataFrame
ts_1h = pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01 00:00+00:00', end='2020-01-02 00:00+00:00', freq='1h')

seed(1)
values = [randint(0, 10) for ts in ts_1h]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Values' : values}, index=ts_1h)

result = df['Values'].rolling(3).agg({'first': lambda rows: rows[0], 'last': lambda rows: rows[-1]})
print(result)

def first(rows):
    return rows[0]

def mylast(rows):
    return rows[-1]

result = df['Values'].rolling(3).agg({'first': first, 'last': last})
print(result)
```

Comment: thanks @furas . A question, I tried to use if in a dict, and it tells me that lambda cannot be used for a Rolling object. Any idea how I can deal with that? `df = df['Values'].rolling(3).agg({'first':'lambda rows: rows[0]'})` - `AttributeError: 'lambda rows: rows[0]' is not a valid function for 'Rolling' object`

Comment: did you try to use directly `lambda` without converting to string `"lambad..."`? Error shows that it doesn't know what to do with this string - probably it expects function's name. You can also try to create normal function `def my_functio(rows): return rows[0]` and use its name in string - `{'first': 'my_functions'}`

Comment: I tested it and you have to use directly `lambad` or function's name - without converting to string. See new code in answer.

Comment: thanks so much @furas, your help is great. Well, you will find me a bit 'heavy' on the topic, but I created her sister question: how doing the same with none numeric type as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60973941  If you have any idea, this would be terrific! :)

Comment: I think it is better to add `tolist()` and then indicate the index, at least this is how it worked for me. For example `<>.agg(lambda rows: rows[0])` should be `<>.agg(lambda rows: rows.tolist()[0])`

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone else needs to find the difference between the first and last value in a 'rolling-window'. I used this on stock market data and wanted to know the price difference from the beginning to the end of the 'window' so I created a new column which used the current row 'close' value and the 'open' value using .shift() so it is taking the "open" value from 60 rows above.

```
df[windowColumn] = df["close"] - (df["open"].shift(60))
```

I think it's a very quick method for large datasets.

Comment: THis works except if index is Timestamp with non continuous dates such as trading holidays and all.