# Taking first value in a rolling window that is not numeric

Tags: python, pandas, rolling-computation

This question follows one I previously asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60940098/taking-first-and-last-value-in-a-rolling-window), and that was answered for numeric values.

I raise this 2nd one now relative to data of Period type.

While the example given below appears simple, I have actually windows that are of **variable size**. Interested in the 1st row of the windows, I am looking for a technic that makes use of this definition.

```
import pandas as pd
from random import seed, randint

# DataFrame
pi1h = pd.period_range(start='2020-01-01 00:00+00:00', end='2020-01-02 00:00+00:00', freq='1h')

seed(1)
values = [randint(0, 10) for ts in pi1h]

df = pd.DataFrame({'Values' : values, 'Period' : pi1h}, index=pi1h)

# This works (numeric type)
df['first'] = df['Values'].rolling(3).agg(lambda rows: rows[0])

# This doesn't (Period type)
df['OpeningPeriod'] = df['Period'].rolling(3).agg(lambda rows: rows[0])
```

Result of 2nd command

```
DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

Please, any idea? Thanks for any help! Bests,

Comment: His previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60940098/taking-first-and-last-value-in-a-rolling-window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First row of rolling window of size `3` means row, which is 2 rows above the current - just use `pd.Series.shift(2)`:

```py
df['OpeningPeriod'] = df['Period'].shift(2)
```

For the variable size (for the sake of example- I took `Values` column as this variable size):

```py
import numpy as np

x=(np.arange(len(df))-df['Values'])

df['OpeningPeriod'] = np.where(x.ge(0), df.loc[df.index[x.tolist()], 'Period'], np.nan)
```

Comment: Hello. As said, in my real situation, the window is of variable size, so I am not able to say by how much I need to shift actually. This is my trouble. This changes for every row.

Comment: I added piece for variable size - same idea, just kind of a custom window shift operation. Let me know, if that's what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! This is it!

Answer (score 0):

Convert your `period[H]` to a `float`

```
# convert to float
df['Period1'] = df['Period'].dt.to_timestamp().values.astype(float)
# rolling and convert back to period
df['OpeningPeriod'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Period1'].rolling(3)\
                                     .agg(lambda rows: rows[0])).dt.to_period('1h')
# drop column
df = df.drop(columns='Period1')
```