Pandas rolling - first value in window
I have code that looks like this
d = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'ix':[0,1,2,3,4,5], 'val': [1,-2,5,4,9,6]})
d['first'] = d['val'].rolling(3).agg(lambda rows: rows[0])

Per the suggestion here Taking first and last value in a rolling window, but I am getting the following error:
ValueError: 0 is not in range

Any idea how I can get the first and last value from a rolling window in pandas?

This occurs because you are trying to access the element of a series that has not yet been fully formed using agg.
For this case I recommend using apply since it is much more flexible in this case, you can see the code with my suggestion below.
d = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'ix':[0,1,2,3,4,5], 'val': [1,-2,5,4,9,6]})
d['first'] = d['val'].rolling(3).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[0] if not x.empty else None)


Thanks, it works. I'm curious, how come that other solution worked in the other case, but not for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60940098/taking-first-and-last-value-in-a-rolling-window
